# Listening for HTML navigation events

Tags: jquery, dom, navigation

Using the DOM API and/or JQuery, is there any way to detect when a user initiates a navigation event (e.g. through clicking on an `a` element with a valid `href`), and bind a listener to it which will be executed before the new HTML page is retrieved and rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/se8osjsj/1/

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    // do stuff here
    return "You are leaving this page, are you sure?";
});
```

OR simply:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    // do stuff here
    return "You are leaving this page, are you sure?";
};
```

> The onbeforeunload event occurs when the document is about to be
>   unloaded.
>
> This event allows you to display a message in a confirmation dialog
>   box to inform the user whether he/she wants to stay or leave the
>   current page.
>
> The default message that appears in the confirmation box, is different
>   in different browsers. However, the standard message is something like
>   "Are you sure you want to leave this page?". This message cannot be
>   removed.
>
> However, you can write a custom message together with the default
>   message. See the first example on this page.
>
> Note: If the onbeforeunload event is not assigned to the 
>   element, you must assign/attach the event on the window object, and
>   use the returnValue property to create a custom message (see syntax
>   examples below).
>
> Note: In Firefox, only the default message will be displayed (not the
>   custom message (if any)).

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Javascript onunload() function is what you are looking for, here is the reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp